# Using Op-amp as comparator with low supply voltage (1.1v)

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc, circuit-design, peltier

As part of a school physics project my group was given 2 TEC1-12706 and was told to find some way to generate electricity via Seeback effect and recycled materials. Due to low efficiency of the TEGs, we are only able to generate around 1.5~1.1V when connecting both TEGs in series during testing. Our idea is to connect the TEG to a pot and use it as an egg timer. Our circuit is as shown:

[image]

[HA17393](https://www.tu-eshop.com/index.php?route=product/product/download&product_id=172&download_id=5275)

At time = 0, the TEG will charge the capacitor.

Few seconds later, due to drop in temperature of hot water, V<sub>se</sub> < V<sub>cap</sub>, stopping charging of capacitor.

Few minutes later, the V<sub>se</sub> < V<sub>non-inverting input</sub> (adjusted using the variable resistor), and op-amp's output will turn on, allowing the capacitor to turn on an LED, or some other device to indicate that the egg is cooked.

However, I am facing an issue with my circuit. Often, when the TEG voltage drops below the capacitor voltage, the capacitor begins to discharge quickly. This happens even if no output is connected to the op-amp. I suspect this is due to the supply voltage of the op-amp being less than stated in the datasheet (V<sub>s</sub> = 2-36V). Is this indeed the case or have I made another design error in my circuit?

Comment: "the capacitor begins to discharge quickly"-  How quickly? What's the time constant? How does it compare to what you would expect from the resistor loading, the Schottky leakage and the quiescent current of the op-amp?  Why use and op-amp as a comparator, why not get a low voltage comparator?

Comment: Also why no current limiting on the LED? Do you want the full near-short circuit current of the op-amp flowing through the LED?  Seems like your timer will vary quite a bit, have you thought about other ways to do this?

Comment: @JohnD that device IS a comparator. I added the spec-link.

Comment: Since the output of the peltier will depend on temperatures this is a really bad way to create a timer. Just making a flasher would probably do.

Comment: @Trevor_G Thanks, I didn't check, I just read the problem statement that called it an op-amp.

Comment: Either the circuit or the description makes no sense. What causes "TEG will stop charging the capacitor" ?

Comment: I have edited the question, is it clearer now? @John No current limiting on the LED as the Voltage is so low that an LED might not even turn on. I'm considering connecting a small motor instead.

Comment: @Trevor Yeah it's a bad way, unfortunately the school project requires us to use electricity generated from waste heat via a TEG. A 555 timer would not work due to low voltage.

Comment: You still have not quantified what "quickly' means. It matters.

Comment: HA17393B has an open-collector output so it can not drive the LED connected that way.

Comment: Also, how are you getting your delta T across the Peltier junction?  Maybe you need better thermal/mechanical design to get more voltage and power from the devices.

Comment: @ThePhoton Just googled a bit on open-collector output. It appears that I am to use connect the output of the op-amp to a bjt/mosfet to drive the LED, am I right?

Comment: @JohnD The hot side is connected to a mess-tin containing boiling water. The cold side is connected to a large metal plate as an impromptu heat sink (no budget is provided for the project)

Comment: @Trevor_G Apologies, I probably should have timed "quickly" in the lab. By "quickly" I mean when I use a bench power supply instead of the TEG, when I drop the the power supply's voltage to 0.5V, the capacitor voltage usually drops accordingly in less than, say, 5 seconds.

Comment: @WetFeet, or connect the LED+R from Vcc to the comparator output and swap the inputs.

Comment: I suspect you're not getting much delta T between hot and cold sides.  Did you use thermal grease between the cold plate and the cold side?  Is there sufficient pressure to maintain good contact? Can you measure delta T? Also, your diode leakage (1mA at 25C), plus the comparator current (0.8mA) plus the load resistors could easily cause a few tenths of a volt per second  of discharge.  If you have only a volt or so on the cap you're going to be in trouble in a few seconds.

Comment: @ThePhoton The LED+R is already connected to the comparator output already though. Or do you mean to connect them to VCC instead?

Comment: Like in [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/93835/6334).